# How to get a linsolve solution in matrix form?

Tags: julia, sympy

Im using SymPy in Julia. My purpose is to solve a homogeneous system of linear equations (Ax=0) with more unknowns than variables (A is not square).
Then, Im using the following code.

```
using SymPy

x, y, z, w = symbols("x y z w")

M = sympy.Matrix(((9, 2, 1,- 4, 0), (-4, -3, -1, -5, 0)))

s = linsolve(M, (x, y, z, w))
```

With this code Im able to get the correct solution. However, I´dont known how to manipulate that solution. 
The final goal is to be able to get the solution in matrix form as lines representing (x and y) and column (z and w). (since x(z, w) and y(z,w)).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If numerical (rather than symbolic) computations are acceptable, then this will get the job done:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> M = rand(2,4)
2×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.497965  0.704514  0.152799  0.69448
 0.594486  0.695488  0.327688  0.710573

julia> Q,R = qr(M);
       C = -R[1:2,1:2]\R[1:2,3:4]
       xy(zw) = C*zw;

# Check that `[xy(zw); zw]` is indeed in the nullspace of `M`:
julia> zw = rand(2)
       M*[xy(zw);zw]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 -2.7755575615628914e-17
 -1.1102230246251565e-16
```